# Steam Community market Buy Orders

Tags: steam, counter-strike-global-offensive, steam-community-market

I'm trying to place a buy order for an item on the steam community market (it's a specific weapon/skin for CS:GO) but there isn't any of the item coming up in the search. Usually what I would do is find the item in the search, open the item page then place a buy order for whatever price I want - but since there's currently 0 for sale I can't open the page for the item and hence I can't place a buy order. Is there some other method to place a buy order?

Answer (score 3):

It is very possible that the skin is not on the Market, as some skins go for up to 10 000$ and the market allows for a maximum price of $400. This is why some skins can only be bought on 3rd party sites or even ebay. What is the skin ?

Comment: He's right. For example there are no factory new MP7 Whiteouts in circulation right now, due to how rare they are.

Comment: @AlexSpencer I know of a skin that was actually sold for 34000$ It was an AK with some rare stickers.

Comment: Jeeze your name is impossible on my keyboard layout... The rarest skin ive seen drop was that one anime AUG in factory new LAST NIGHT. one guy on the opposing team got it and the whole server burst out into "OOHHHHH". something like £500 or something crazy from an end of match drop. My most expensive skin is... uhm... My butterfly (unskinned), or my Deagle Blaze. because im poor and cant afford a multi thousand pound skin

Comment: @AlexSpencer You sure did Alex :D

Comment: and now im sat here very confused by your last statement.

Comment: @AlexSpencer Elsewhere you asked if you had commented on me before. So I decided to throw you off, by answering your question here. Job well done :D

Comment: ah. you did a very good job of throwing me off. Now allow me to just find a new brain as you may have broken my current one more than the last time i got AWPed

Answer (score 0):

This may be a steam bug, in this case you can report it on their website or contact support.
To get skins easier, you can register on a website such as bitskins.com or opskins.net or the various other skin trading websites there are on the internet. You can then deposit money into the account for the respective website and buy skins directly from the website. These websites tend to be better than steam market anyways as there are constant sales and the prices are much cheaper than you can find on steam market.

Answer (score 0):

The Steam Market page for an item is created after someone has offered to sell the item for the first time.

For instance, if you check a game which was recently accepted for the feature of "Steam trading cards", e.g. [Clea 2](https://www.steamcardexchange.net/index.php?gamepage-appid-1257860), this is how the page looks for one of its items ([:florinehappy:](https://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/753/1257860-%3Aflorinehappy%3A)):

[image: No listing]